# Using Wget to download files with a specific name off a site

Tags: wget

What would be the best way to look down through a (semi) top level domain and all it's subfolders for occurrences of certain number letter combinations.

I have several folders with large lists of images and only need to obtain ones with occurrences of certain numbers. I.e: 282 or 191

bonus points if you can tell me how to filter out a minimum size so i'm not downloading thumbnails along with the higher resolution photos.

Comment: What is your operating system?

Comment: Mac OS X Yosemite

Answer (score 0):

This will crawl a site looking for gif,png,jpg,jpeg, then grep those results for any strings. The resulting list is then retrieved to the specified directory by wget. You need to adjust '/path/to/save/files', as well as the url to grab the files from.

Adjust the final grep statement to define your search parameters. It would be:

```
grep "191\|282" --instead of-- grep "taco.gif\|whatever"
```

Note: If you add or remove any file types, modify both the -A flag parameters and the last grep accordingly.

```
wget -P /path/to/save/files/ $(wget --spider --execute robots=off \
--user-agent="Mozilla/5.0 Firefox4.0.1" --no-clobber --random-wait --force-html \
--recursive --no-directories -A gif,png,jpg,jpeg http://taco.com 2>&1 | grep -e \
'http\|Length\|broken link' | awk -F' ' '{ print $3 }' | sed '$!N;s/\n/ /' | grep \
'.gif\|.png\|.jpg\|.jpeg' | tr -d '()' | sed '/does$/d' | sort -k2 | \
grep "taco.gif\|whatever")
```

Note: This won't work on a lot of sites as most admins block wget and have scripts to block crawlers, but it works fine on taco.com.

I haven't tried it, but this batch downloader plugin might work better.
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fatkun-batch-download-ima/nnjjahlikiabnchcpehcpkdeckfgnohf?hl=en

Comment: Unfortunately all the files are of the same type on the server so it's just trying to grab them all. How would I modify that to search and grab only files that have certain serial numbers likes "282" or "191"?